# Translating Stata to R - recoding

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to translate the following from Stata

```
clear
set obs 1000
generate y = floor((10-0+1)*runiform() +0)
recode y (7=0) (8=0) (9=1) (10=2)
```

I thought I had it with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- y ~ floor((10-0+1)*runif(1000)+0)
recode (mydata, '7'=0, '8'=0, '9'=1, '10'=2)
```

However, the last line keeps giving me an error:

> Error in UseMethod("recode"):no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "formula".

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `mydata <- floor((10-0+1)*runif(1000)+0)`

Comment: Minor details: `10 - 0 + 1` is `11`, always and in both Stata and R. Similarly, adding `0` is useless. In both cases, if these are steps towards something more general, then fine, but that is not at all obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cut`:

```
n = 1000L
y = cut(runif(n, 0, 11), c(-Inf, 9, 10, Inf), right = FALSE, ordered = TRUE)
```

You can see how it worked with `table`:

```
# y
#  [-Inf,9)    [9,10) [10, Inf) 
#       813        91        96
```

If you really want the codes, you can use `as.integer(y)-1L`. Read `?cut` and `?factor` for more details on ordinal data in R.

---

I've been assuming so far that there is some rhyme or reason to the recoding rule. If there is not, best to store it in a separate table and draw values from there (which is the same thing I would do in Stata):

```
rec = data.frame(old = c(7,8,9,10), new = c(0,0,1,2))

n  = 1000L
y  = floor(runif(n, 0, 11))
DF = data.frame(id = 1:10, y)

library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[rec, on=c(y = "old"), y := new]
DF[, .N, keyby=y]

#    y   N
# 1: 0 288
# 2: 1 179
# 3: 2 174
# 4: 3 101
# 5: 4  82
# 6: 5  93
# 7: 6  83
```

You'd need to install the data.table package for this to work, though.

Comment: Cool answer, @Frank, but any clue how to perform the recoding using only `base R`?Thxs

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas I think something involving the `match` function would work, maybe `m = match(DF$y, rec$old); DF$y = ifelse(is.na(m), DF$y, rec$new[m])` You could also post a bounty to see if someone else has a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty